# How to skip tag on master page depending on content page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a `MasterPage`, but want to skip one `tag` that is placed on `MasterPage` when particular `ContentPage` is loading. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: what do u mean by skip? please elaborate clearly!

Comment: I mean not to display it on content page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the master's codebind:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPageName page = this.Page as ContentPageName;
    myTag.Visible = page == null;
}
```